# Logging Apache POI standalone application

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-poi, apache-commons-logging

I'm trying to log the operations that are performed inside Apache POI API with log4j.

I have the following configurations in a properties file:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.poi=DEBUG, apachepoi
log4j.additivity.apachepoi=false
log4j.appender.apachepoi=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.apachepoi.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.apachepoi.File=c:\\logs\\apachepoi.log
log4j.appender.apachepoi.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.apachepoi.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %x: %m%n
```

And, with NetBeans, I'm assigning the following VM options:

```
Dorg.apache.poi.util.POILogger=org.apache.poi.util.CommonsLogger -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
```

The "apachepoi.log" file is created but no lines are written in it.
Weirdest things of all: if I had the VM options to a JBoss instance it logs the operations of Apache POI. The problem is that I need it on a standalone application

-- edit

Also tried under a Linux environment but remains the same: with JBoss the logs are written but not on a standalone app

Comment: `commons-logging.jar` is in your project, right?

Comment: Right. The libs are the same for both webapp and standalone app

Comment: Well, since JBoss is a full JEE server, it is loading other libraries apart from what you put in your application. That would be one way of explaining your results and why I asked.

Comment: That may be a reason, but I can log using Log4j in the standalone app...

Comment: Might be because Apache POI currently uses a custom logging framework rather than using log4j or slf4j. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/POILogger.html The dev team is currently considering switching to a standard library. Contributions and discussion are welcome on dev@poi.apache.org mailing list.